# How to replace all non-numeric values in a varchar Column with a 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to convert a column table to BIGINT, but first I need to remove all junk data

This means, I have to remove all the non-numeric data in this column and replace this with a zero so I can update the table type

How I can achieve this in SQL Server?

Thanks!

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData
(
    Col1 VARCHAR(100)
)

-- I want to remove this kind of data
INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES('<font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">2007220737724</font></')

-- I want to keep this kind of data
INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES('2007220737724')
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Edit: Added some sample data

Comment: But what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems simple enough, you can just use `try_cast` and replace all non valid data with `'0'`

```
update t
set col1='0'
where try_cast(col1 as bigint) is null
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your data is *almost* valid XML, just missing a proper closing tag.

Assuming it was valid, you could use XQuery

```sql
SELECT CAST(Col1 AS xml).value('(font/font/text())[1]','bigint')
FROM SampleData
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=51c5badb773c763057db7c58c465e411)